# Rotation Angle in Pose Orientation

Tags: ros, pose, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 2D image on which I conduct an algorithm to find its rotation, and I get it in radian. No problem until here.

Now that I want to fill in the pose object with what I collected from the 2D vision, I get stuck at where to insert the rotation. I do know I cannot fill in everything, I don't intend to, either. I only need the position (I have it already) and the rotation.

```
            obj.pose.position.x = v['pose'][0] #x 
            obj.pose.position.y = v['pose'][1] #y 
            obj.pose.position.z = v['pose'][2] #z
           
             # which one below is the one I should use to pass the rotation angle?
            obj.pose.orientation.x = v['pose'][3] 
            obj.pose.orientation.y = v['pose'][4]
            obj.pose.orientation.z = v['pose'][5]
            obj.pose.orientation.w = v['pose'][6]
```

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** So I came up with the following after the useful insights given by the commentators.

```
       self.some_srv = rospy.Service("/bla/request_poses", PartArray, self.some_service_srv)

       def some_service_srv(self, req):
         # some irrelevant stuff happening here

        # this is where the actual thing shall happen
        obj.pose.position.x = v['pose'][0]
        obj.pose.position.y = v['pose'][1]
        obj.pose.position.z = v['pose'][2]
        rotation_angle = v['pose'][3] # extract the rotation angle
        zaxis = (0, 0, 1) #rotation is around the Z axis in the image
        quaternion = quaternion_about_axis(rotation_angle, zaxis) # use rotation angle + axis to get the quaternion
        obj.pose.orientation.x = quaternion[0]
        obj.pose.orientation.y = quaternion[1]
        obj.pose.orientation.z = quaternion[2] # this is the rotation we are talking about
        obj.pose.orientation.w = quaternion[3]
        
        list_detected.part_array.append(obj)
        return list_detected
```

This runs, however I always get 0 values for all of the quarternions, which is somehow nonsense because the rotation angle is definitely non-zero (I print its value).

```
            position: 
              x: 274.0
              y: 250.0
              z: 602.0
            orientation: 
              x: 0.0
              y: 0.0
              z: 0.0
              w: 0.0
```

I print the quarternion list separately, and there is a non-zero value inside, which seems fine, but I don't know why the published value gets zero.

```
         [0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 3.061617e-17 1.000000e+00]
```

I also printed the value of rotation (in radian) and here are some values of it:

```
0.980580687945
6.12323399574e-17
-0.707106781187
0.294085862655
-1.0
0.56419054038
-0.0114934175734
6.12323399574e-17
6.12323399574e-17
-1.0
0.707106781187
6.12323399574e-17
```

And this is how I get the angle using OpenCV:

```
# helper function to find out which side of the rectangle is longer, then add the angle appropriately
def getAngle(rect):
    angle = rect[2]
    width, height = rect[1]
    if (width < height):
        return math.cos(math.radians(angle + 180))
    else:
        return math.cos(math.radians(angle + 90))



...
 # Find contours:
    (im, contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(im, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = contours[0]

    # get the rotated rectangle to get the rotation
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    rotation = getAngle(rect) # in radians
...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314664/rotation-angle-in-pose-orientation/) by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2019-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kosmastsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/36854/kosmastsk/) on 2019-02-04**:
Considering that the image is on the xy plane, I would say that the rotation is on the orientation.z. Think of it, as turning the image around the z axis, but keeping the other axes stable. If the image is not on one axis, it may be more complicated though

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-04**:
It is indeed more complicated than that, in all cases I'm afraid. See my answer below.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-05**:
Even if your rotation was zero the quaternion would contain positive values. The quaternion values you printed out is very small (x10-17) so is being rounded to zero. There appears to be a problem with the `quaternion_about_axis` function since it's returning an invalid rotation quaternion.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-05**:
Is the function problematic or the way I use it? I don't get it. Is there a bug in ROS, seriously?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-05**:
The function definitely works, can you show us more of your code. It's probably something about how your getting the values into the message.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-05**:
I edited my question, butt there isn't much to write really, I mean, I wrote all that is relevant. It's just a service which is called, and it should return the pose (position + quarternion). Position values are filled in, no problem, but the quaternion values are always zero for some reason.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-05**:
Can you print the value and type of `v['pose'][3]` is this not numeric then it may explain this behaviour. I've just checked the syntax and I think you're doing anything obvious wrong. The function really should be returning a 4D unit vector

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-05**:
One of the values your printing out `6.12323399574e-17` is **Exactly** twice the value in the quaternion of `3.061617e-17` I suspect there is some other code you haven't put in your question which is causing the problem. Can you post all your code which is producing the problem.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-06**:
I put everything on the ROS side. If you want to see the OpenCV side (how I get the rotation angle out of 2D vision) I can do that too, I doubt it is relevant though.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-06**:
I've just checked and the values coming out of the `quaternion_about_axis` function are correct, but there must be a bug between there and where your publishing the pose. Can you post **all** your code between this function and the `publish` call so we can try and find where it's going wrong.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-06**:
Normally I couldn't do this due to confidential issues but now I found that I can give a time-based link, so perhaps you can look at it, and if you find the problem, we could reshape the question without exposing the code. [Here](https://pastebin.com/3aLp5Xgh) for a short amount of time.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-06**:
There are still no ros publishers in that code. But I think you need to carefully debug through the code because the orientation values are not being copied at some point. The `quaternion_about_axis` function calculates them correctly but the values are not making it into the pose message you show.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-06**:
I traced the values until the end of the function and they are fine, but then it's all about the ROS service, which returns them as zero. It's really weird, I am about to call it a bug almost. Never seen such a thing before tbh, but I am not the ROS master either. Anyway, thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The quaternion for a given Z axis (yaw) rotation is given by:

`w = cos(theta / 2)`
`x = 0`
`y = 0`
`z = sin(theta / 2)`

where theta is the yaw angle in radians. If X (roll) or Y (pitch) axis rotations are involved too, the formula is a little more tedious, and can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Euler_Angles_to_Quaternion_Conversion).

The `tf` library has very helpful functions for constructing quaternions from Euler angles. For yaw quaternions, there is `tf::createQuaternionFromYaw(double yaw)` which takes a single argument which is the yaw angle in radians and returns a tf::Quaternion object that is equivalent. There is also `tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(double yaw)` (notice the 'Msg') which is similar, but returns a geometry_msgs::Quaternion ROS message.

For all three axes, there is `tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(double roll, double pitch, double yaw)` and `tf::createQuaternionMsgFromRollPitchYaw(double roll, double pitch, double yaw)`.

Of course, this is all available in C++ by including `<tf/tf.h>`. In Python, it looks like you can convert Euler angles into a quaternion using `transformations.py` ([doc_link](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/hydro-devel/tf/src/tf/transformations.py)). I haven't used it myself before though.

---

Originally posted by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) with karma: 956 on 2019-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-05**:
I am not using C++, but the Python equivalent of what you are saying should be `quaternion_about_axis(angle, axis)`, right? All I have is angle around the axis Z, so this should be it. Edited the question.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2019-02-05**:
Also make sure your quaternions are always normalized otherwise most operations you will do on them will yeld undefined behavior.

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-05**:
Thanks for the warning. Do you have any normalization example I can take a look at?

**Comment by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) on 2019-02-05**:
The quaternion should never be all zeros, as it is always should be a unit-length vector. I would first try manually computing w and z according to the formula in my answer and make sure that you at least get the result that way to rule out any weirdness

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-05**:
It's not all zeros though: `[0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 3.061617e-17 1.000000e+00]` does this also look weird?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2019-02-05**:
This looks fine, 3.0e-17 is a very small number, close enough to zero. The norm is this quaternion is 1 so you are good.

**Comment by [robustify](https://answers.ros.org/users/26169/robustify/) on 2019-02-05**:
Oh, didn't notice that w is 1! Yes, that is a valid quaternion, but it seems like the angle you passed into it is very close to zero. A quaternion with w = 1 and the rest are zero represents no rotation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rotations in ROS are described using [rotation quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), which are represented by the four orientation values you see in the pose message. A rotation quaternion must be a 4D unit vector for it to be valid, and it is non-trivial to calculate the elements yourself.

However there are useful helper classes to do this for you. The [tf2::Quaternion object](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1Quaternion.html) has a constructor which accepts angle and axis representation which is exactly what you want in your case. You have a known rotation and you know it's about the Z axis. So if you use this constructor to create a quaternion object you can then use its `getX(), getY() . . getW()` methods to calculate the values you need.

Hope this makes sense.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-02-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-02-04**:
My rotation is about the Z axis yes, correct. I'll then create that object accordingly and then I'll call those methods to assign  `obj.pose.orientation.w` and so on? Which of these is the rotation though? I still don't know that. Is it Z?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-04**:
They are all the rotation. Quaternions are not an easy thing to get your head around, I recommend reading all of the Wikipedia page I linked, to give you an introduction.